# Why does a circle in the complex plane get "deformed" under a complex map?

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am currently learning complex analysis.
I am told that

> small circles centred at $\alpha$, when mapped under $f$, are scaled
>   by $\lvert f'(\alpha)\rvert$ and rotated anticlockwise by
>   $\arg(f'(\alpha))$

That is fine, but does anyone know of any "accessible" tutorials or **even can someone give me an intuitive explanation of why this is so?**

I can see that if the function is holomorphic on $K$ then for small $h$ 
$$f(\alpha+h) - f(\alpha) \approx hf'(\alpha)$$

so intervals $[x,x+h]$ are stretched in some way.

Comment: I think you already have provided a quite intuitive explanation. Just consider that $h$ as a vector (a complex number).

Comment: It then follows immediately from complex multiplication.

Comment: Have a look at "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham if you look for intuition in complex analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that multiplication by a *complex* constant $f'(\alpha)$ corresponds to a stretching by $\lvert f'(\alpha) \rvert$ and a rotation by it's argument.

Comment: It clicked after flawr's comment. Damn I am starting to love complex numbers. :(